# Java: Shuffling Cards in a Deck using Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle

I am trying to implement a Perfect Shuffle method where it will split a deck into 2 and then interweave the cards so you have one from each deck being placed into the new deck. When I try to run my current program, the output I would get is:

```
Results of 3 consecutive perfect shuffles:
   1: 0 4 1 5 2 6 3
   2: 0 2 4 6 1 3 5
   3: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I do not understand why I get 0 as my first value for each time I shuffle the deck. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? This is my code:

```
class Ideone {
/**
 * The number of consecutive shuffle steps to be performed in each call
 * to each sorting procedure.
 */
private static final int SHUFFLE_COUNT = 3;

/**
 * The number of values to shuffle.
 */
private static final int VALUE_COUNT = 7;

/**
 * Tests shuffling methods.
 * @param args is not used.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Results of " + SHUFFLE_COUNT +
                             " consecutive perfect shuffles:");
    int[] values1 = new int[VALUE_COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
        values1[i] = i;
        }
    for (int j = 1; j <= SHUFFLE_COUNT; j++) {
        perfectShuffle(values1);
        System.out.print("  " + j + ":");
        for (int k = 0; k < values1.length; k++) {
            System.out.print(" " + values1[k]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
   public static void perfectShuffle(int[] values) {
    int[] temp = new int[values.length];
    int halfway = (values.length +1)/2;
    int position = 0;

    for (int j = 0 ; j < halfway; j++)
    {
        temp[position] = values[j];   
        position +=2;
    }

    position = 1; 
    for (int k = halfway; k < values.length; k++)
    {
        temp[position] = values[k];
        position +=2;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < values.length; k++)
        values[k] = temp[k];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

array index begin at 0 and not 1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
        values1[i] = i;
        }
```

you are copying 0 in values1 in this for loop in your main method which you then pass to perfectShuffle

Answer (score 0):

You fill the "deck" starting at 0 and then shuffle, but your shuffle always puts the "0" card first so it never really gets shuffled in. You can see the same thing with the #1 using:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < values1.length+1; i++) {
        values1[i-1] = i;
    }
```

Also, with an even number of cards, your last card will never change either.